# open file using navigateToURL

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I'm making an android file browser app designed with as3. I finished designing every thing now I just need a way to open a file (image, video, pdf.. etc). right now I'm using this code:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(File.desktopDirectory.url + "/" + fileName, "_blank"));
```

on pc it opens the file in the default web browser but on android device it only opens the file in "google drive" app as a pdf and shows error message that the choosen file is not a pdf file and when disabling "google drive" it does nothing.
 can you please tell me whats wrong? or give me a way to open a file?
I know this is a dublicate but none of other solutions worked for me.

Comment: have you tried the `File` class and `myFile.openWithDefaultApplication();` ?

Comment: @MartonPallagi it only works on pc not on android device

Comment: `navigateToURL` is for web page URLs not for opening any files. If `openWithDefaultApplication();` only works on PC then there is something wrong with your testing Android device. Did you reset it (lost "Default Application" settings)? Under normal Android usage does tapping an mp3 file or jpeg also open both with Google PDF too? Make sure mp3 is set to open with Audio Player and that jpeg opens with Gallery then later AS3 code using `openWithDefaultApplication();` will also work fine.

Comment: @VC.One every thing works fine on my android device using the default file manager (opening mp3 and jpeg files). I have seen other users having the same problem with openWithDefaultApplication()  method. its not supported on air on android if you tried it and it worked with you please let me know. other forums suggested to use navigateToURL() method to open files in other apps using URI scheme and that's what I'm trying to do know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to use an ANE like this:
https://github.com/illuzor/Android-File-Extension-ANE
after downloading the zip extract it then include the ANE in the bin folder in your project then import
com.illuzor.fileextension.FileExtension to your project from source_as3 folder then type

```
FileExtension.openFile(file);
```

where "file" is the file object you want to open. I tested it on adnroid device and it worked.
NOTE: you need AIR SDK 18 or latest.